# How do I set textarea size to x cols, y rows using CSS

Tags: html, css

My textarea I was using

`<textarea cols="50" rows="20">`

and that worked fine. But I realized I needed to adjust the size for smaller displays (such as mobile) so I then used width and height attributes with CSS

i.e

```css
.genre_grey_list {
  width: 50ch;
  height: 20em;
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="20"></textarea>
<textarea class="genre_grey_list"></textarea>
```

However a width of *50ch* is less than cols="50", and  a height of *20em* is less than rows="20". How can I accurately set size of textarea in terms of rows and columns using CSS ?

Comment: Maybe it could be possible to find a method given a specific font-family, font-size, line-height and a letter-spacing: or are you looking for a general-purpose solution?

Comment: general purpose, seems like a very straightfoward task